# Generate single case class from Seq of case classes

Tags: scala

I have 2 case classes

```
case class First(vt: Long, slots: Seq[Second])
case class Second(index: Int, a: Long, b: Long, c: Long, d: Long)
```

I have one Seq like below

```
Seq(First(200,Seq(Second(2,2,4,2,4), Second(3,1,1,1,1))), 
First(100,Seq(Second(2,1,3,1,3), Second(1,1,4,1,4))))
```

I want to generate single case class from above seq where
 vt max of vts from 2 instances of First i.e. max(100, 200) i.e. 200
each instance of Seq in below First is - (index, min(a), max(b), min(c), max(d)) for example

```
Seq(Second(2,2,4,2,4), Second(2,1,3,1,3)) -> Second(2,min(2,1),max(4,3),min(2,1),max(4,3))
```

Final output should be

```
First(200, Seq(Second(1,1,4,1,4),Second(2,1,4,1,4),Second(3,1,1,1,1))
```

Comment: Could you please explain the question in a little depth? The result Seq[Second] has only 3 elements and not 4 why ?

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar..we need to generate seq based on condition, if there is > 1 entry in seq w.r.t index (which is index 2 here), then need to merge 2 instances of second to single, based on rule...Seq(Second(2,2,4,2,4), Second(2,1,3,1,3)) -> Second(2,min(2,1),max(4,3),min(2,1),max(4,3))---> Second(2,1,4,1,4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

```
case class Second(index: Int, a: Long, b: Long, c: Long, d: Long)
case class First(vt: Long, slots: Seq[Second])

val seq = Seq(First(200,Seq(Second(2,2,4,2,4), Second(3,1,1,1,1))),
  First(100,Seq(Second(2,1,3,1,3), Second(1,1,4,1,4))))
```

**Max vt**

```
val maxFirst = seq.map(_.vt).max
```

**Sort, group, filter, etc the Seconds**

```
val seqOfSecond = seq.map(_.slots).flatten

val groupedSecond = seqOfSecond.groupBy(_.index).toSeq.sortBy(_._1).toMap
// Map(1 -> List(Second(1,1,4,1,4)), 2 -> List(Second(2,2,4,2,4), Second(2,1,3,1,3)), 3 -> List(Second(3,1,1,1,1)))

val groupedSecondFlat = groupedSecond.map {
  case (k, v) =>
    Second(v.head.index, v.map(_.a).min, v.map(_.b).max, v.map(_.c).min, v.map(_.d).max)
}.toSeq
// List(Second(1,1,4,1,4), Second(2,1,4,1,4), Second(3,1,1,1,1))
```

**Bring it together**

```
First(maxFirst, groupedSecondFlat)
// First(200,List(Second(1,1,4,1,4), Second(2,1,4,1,4), Second(3,1,1,1,1)))
```

**Pop it in an ugly-looking function**

```
def doStuffToFirsts(seq: Seq[First]) = {
  val maxFirst = seq.map(_.vt).max
  val seqOfSecond = seq.flatMap(_.slots)
  val groupedSecond = seqOfSecond.groupBy(_.index).toSeq.sortBy(_._1).toMap.map {
    case (k, v) =>
      Second(v.head.index, v.map(_.a).min, v.map(_.b).max, v.map(_.c).min, v.map(_.d).max)
  }.toSeq

  First(maxFirst, groupedSecond)
}
```